# Grouping consecutive values

Tags: python, pandas

Below, I have sample input and output data. Input data is the dataframe `g_input` like

```
  0 1 2 3 4 5
0 1 0 1 1 1 1
1 0 1 1 1 0 0
2 0 1 1 1 1 1
3 1 1 0 1 1 1
4 1 1 1 1 0 0
5 0 0 1 0 1 0
6 1 1 1 0 1 0
```

The Intermediate output called `g_intermediate` would look like:

```
  0 1 2 3 4 5
0 1 0 4 4 4 4
1 0 3 3 3 0 0
2 0 5 5 5 5 5
3 2 2 0 3 3 3
4 4 4 4 4 0 0 
5 0 0 1 0 1 0 
6 3 3 3 0 1 0
```

Then I have multiple thresholds for consecutive occurrences:

`Threshold_dd=2
 Threshold_mm=3
 Threshold_hh=4`

For `Threshold_dd=2`, the output `Out_1` would look like:

```
  0 1 2 3 4 5
0 0 0 1 1 1 1
1 0 1 1 1 0 0
2 0 1 1 1 1 1
3 0 0 0 1 1 1
4 1 1 1 1 0 0 
5 0 0 0 0 0 0 
6 1 1 1 0 0 0
```

For `Threshold_mm`, the output `Out_2` would look like:

```
  0 1 2 3 4 5
0 0 0 1 1 1 1
1 0 0 0 0 0 0
2 0 1 1 1 1 1
3 0 0 0 0 0 0
4 1 1 1 1 0 0 
5 0 0 0 0 0 0 
6 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

For `Threshold_hh=4`, the output `Out_3` would look like:

```
  0 1 2 3 4 5
0 0 0 1 1 1 1
1 0 0 0 0 0 0
2 0 1 1 1 1 1
3 0 0 0 0 0 0
4 0 0 0 0 0 0 
5 0 0 0 0 0 0 
6 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

I tried the following:

```
g_intermediate = g_input.apply((g_input.groupby, axis=1) != g.shift(periods=1, axis=1)\
            .cumsum(axis=1)).transform('size') * g(axis=1)
```

For any threshold,`threshold = x`

```
outputs =(g_intermediate > threshold).astype(int)
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: what you are looking for is really `g_intermediate` right? because the output with the threshold you know how to do it according to what you wrote? also in what you tried gg = .. it is mentioned  `g`, what is it?

Comment: @Ben.T,  The code for 'g_intermediate' and 'outputs' do not  work. My final out put would look like the 'out_1',  'out_2',  'out_3'.

Answer (score 2):

We need `stack` then multiple `groupby` with `cumsum` and `transform` `count`

```
s=df.stack().diff().ne(0).groupby(level=0).cumsum()
s=s.groupby([s.index.get_level_values(0),s]).transform('count').unstack()
thresh=2
s.gt(thresh).astype(int)
   0  1  2  3  4  5
0  0  0  1  1  1  1
1  0  1  1  1  0  0
2  0  1  1  1  1  1
3  0  0  0  1  1  1
4  1  1  1  1  0  0
5  0  0  0  0  0  0
6  1  1  1  0  0  0
```

Comment: the `groupby(level=0)` is not really necessary at the first line, because you groupby `s.index.get_level_values(0)` as well in the second line?

Comment: @Ben.T I tried your suggestion as follows: `s=df.stack().diff().ne(0).cumsum(); s=s.groupby([s]).transform('count').unstack();    thresh=2;                                   
out= s.gt(thresh).astype(int)`  The output I am getting is wrong. Thank you.

Comment: @Chane you still need the `s.index.get_level_values(0)` in the `groupby` of the second line, `s=s.groupby([s.index.get_level_values(0), s])...` I was just taking about the `groupby(level=0)` in the first line if I remember well

Comment: @Ben.T It is not giving the desired intermediate output. I am not getting the following.                                                                                                          `  0 1 2 3 4 5
0 1 0 4 4 4 4
1 0 3 3 3 0 0
2 0 5 5 5 5 5
3 2 2 0 3 3 3
4 4 4 4 4 0 0 
5 0 0 1 0 1 0 
6 3 3 3 0 1 0`

Comment: @Chane I agree you don't get the intermediate result you just posted in the comment, but using `groupby(level=0)` or not does not change the intermediate result obtained with this method (at least on the short try I just did)

Comment: @Ben.T It returns ones when there are zero values more than the threshold.

Comment: @Ben.T It returns ones when there are zero values more than the threshold. for `data=  0 0 0 0 ; Threshold =2; ourput= 1 1 1 1` However, What I need is to return ones only for 3 or more consecutive above zero values eg. for `data= 3, 2, 5 0 ; Threshold =2; ourput= 1 1 1 0` I tried `gt(0)` instead of  `ne(0)` in the first line. Still not working.

Comment: @Chane I see, but this is not related to the `groupby(level=0)` I commented about, it is related to the original answer of YOBEN_S. Like this I would say a quick fix is to use `where` in the last line to replace the spot where is was 0 by 0 in s like `s.where(df.ne(0), 0).gt(thresh).astype(int)`, but if not working, then see with the original person who answered :)